# $5$ movies up for $10$ awards, how many ways to distribute

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

There are $5$ movies up for $10$ awards, how many ways can we distribute these awards?

My guess is $\left(\!\!{5\choose 10}\!\!\right)$. Is this correct?

Comment: What does $\left(\!\!{5\choose 10}\!\!\right)$ mean?

Comment: I'm guessing it is _suppose_ to be $10\choose 5$, but that's not correct.

Answer (score 1):

We have two answers here, $14 \choose 4$ or $5^{10}$, I think that depends on our understanding of the problem.

1) 10 awards are identical. All that matters is how many awards each movie gets.

Think of this problem as you have 14 stuffs. Among them 4 are separators, rest 10 are the awards. By placing the 4 separators (or say, think of pick 4 out of 14 as separators), the 10 awards are naturally partitioned into 5 parts (even empty counts). You view these 5 parts as 5 movies bearing the awards. For example:

$$ A S A A S A A A A A A A S S$$

$S$ represents separators, $A$ represents awards. In this case, first movie got one award, third movie got 7 awards...

The formula:

$${n + k - 1 \choose k - 1} = {14 \choose 4}$$

2) 10 awards are not identical, just like the Oscars.

Then it applies to use $k^n = 5^{10}$ in this case, meaning that for each of $n$ distinct awards, $k$ candidates make it $k$ possibilities.

Though it is a simple counting problem, we should take it more carefully, which I myself failed to do previously.

Answer (score 0):

This is another stars-and-bars problem: you want to find the number of solutions to $A_1+A_2+A_3+A_4+A_5=10$ , where $A_i$ is the number of awards given to the $i-th$ movie. This is $(5+10-1) C (5-1)=14C4$, i.e., "14 choose 4". The general number of non-negative solutions to $x_1+x_2+..+x_k=n$ is $(n+k-1)C(k-1)$

Answer (score 0):

The answer is equivalent to creating $10$-length string where each element of the string can be filled up in $5$ ways

$(A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J)$, here $A$ to $J$ are are all 10 different awards.

Each award can be given in $5$ different ways to 5 different movies.

So,the answers is $5^{10}$

Answer (score 0):

If one movie can get more than one award.

First award can be given in 5 ways, second award can be given in 5 ways and so on for all the 10 awards.

Ans=$5^{10}$ ways

Comment: How exactly is your answer different than mine? Rather it was posted later than me! What do you say about that?

Comment: @Hawk, pls read it is explained in different manner.

Comment: Looks like the same to me. Just the same concept with a little different representation.

Comment: @Hawk, I am not a mathematician to come up with a "new" concept.

Comment: Certainly you are not, but you can always apply the concepts you know in different aspects and different concepts you know in one specific aspect.All I am saying is that, why post a similar answer when one has been already posted before you could do?